Azure function v2 (python), host.json error in VScode, "Matches multiple schemas when only one must validate"
I'm building an Azure function v2 (python), I have the following host.json error in VScode.
Matches multiple schemas when only one must validate.
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}

Any ideas how to solve

Its a warning message which is being thrown after having the correct schema as per MS Doc but your function will work as expected and the debugger will also the read the host.json file when you will execute it.
When you will execute the function using func host start --verbose command, it will read the host.json file and provide you the expected function output.


I have raised a github issue to know more about the warning message, you can keep an eye on it for any latest update.

@Jimmy3421 are you able to get the output from the function?

it's too long for the comment

Can you please update in the question
